# rsync after upgrade to 14.04.3 lost

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, rsync

I am helpless. After upgrade to ubuntu 14.04.3 on my server, rsync ist not working any more. After starting `rsync -av /data1/ /mnt/sdb2` (for example) there follows output

```
sending incremental file list 
treeinfo.wc
Getötet (german, stands for killed).
```

After that rsync is no more available. It is deleted from `/usr/bin` directory!!

Doing `apt-get install rsync` says "last version is installed". I can `apt-get remove rsync` and then `apt-get install rsync`. And the problem starts from beginning.

Does anybody has a explanation and/or a hint for me to get my beloved rsync back ??

Comment: Can you tell (or use pastebin.com, remember strip up privacy) any output of command with more verbosity? Something like `rsync -avvv ~/data1/ /mnt/sdb2`.

Maybe you can look for error code of rsync by using `echo $?` after the error, then look up this list http://wpkg.org/Rsync_exit_codes as a start.